# vsftpd whitelisting

Tags: linux, security, ftp, vsftpd, whitelist

How do you whitelist IPs for the service to allow only certain subnets on? Do I use IPTables or is there an easier way like IPWrappers Do you have to register the service for it to work with IPWrappers(hosts.allow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your vsftpd has been compiled with tcp_wrappers support then you can use it if you turn on the vsftpd configurstion option

> tcp_wrappers=yes
>
> If enabled, and vsftpd was compiled with tcp_wrappers support, incoming connections will be fed through tcp_wrappers access control. Furthermore, there is a mechanism for per-IP based configuration. If tcp_wrappers sets the VSFTPD_LOAD_CONF environment variable, then the vsftpd session will try and load the vsftpd configuration file specified in this variable.

You can then use the standard [hosts.allow](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow) and [hosts.deny](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow) files.

You can check to see if your vsftpd has been compiled with libwrap support like so

```
ldd /usr/sbin/vsftpd | grep wrap
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00002ae164bb6000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.0/24 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 4.5.6.0/24 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j DROP
```

to allow from 1.2.3.0/24 and 4.5.6.0/24 and dissallow from everyone else.

Don't forget to save iptables configuration (depends on your linux distro), so it will survive reboot.